# Session does not work in Composite C1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, c1-cms

I started integrating Composite C1 with an existing ASP.Net Website Project.

Putting some usercontrols which use SessionState into a MasterPage resulted in an error, saying that SessionState was not enabled.

I tried to set

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" enableSessionState="true">
```

in the web.config then and add

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="30" />
```

but no success still.

Why does Session State not work and how can I enable it for my Composite C1 Project?

Comment: which version of the masterpages are you using? There was a bug in the earlier versions where IRequireSessionState wasn't implemented on the Page-object.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "version of the masterpages". I got the latest stable release from codeplex: Composite C1 2.1.1 (2.1.4113.99)

Comment: Masterpages are not a core part of C1 and im not sure how good they are at updating the package on their server. You should try getting the newest version from http://compositec1contrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets.

Comment: this particular issue was fixed in the checkin from july 6th so thats pretty long time ago, but i don't know how often Composite is updating their package server http://compositec1contrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/3f14f6e15ce4

Comment: First of all: Thanks a lot (again), I will check it out right away. Quick question: Are all the versions there stable and safe for production environments?

Comment: In the Contrib project the MasterPages, Razor and SiteMapProvider is production ready, im using it myself on several large installations. For C1 i have no issues either running the newest changesets, running those on several large installations as well :)

Comment: Heh, I am completely lost right now. Can you help me figure out how the Contrib project works? http://compositec1contrib.codeplex.com/discussions/278428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masterpages are not a core part of C1 and im not sure how good they are at updating the package on their server. You should try getting the newest version from http://compositec1contrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets.

This particular issue was fixed in the checkin from july 6th so thats pretty long time ago, but i don't know how often Composite is updating their package server http://compositec1contrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/3f14f6e15ce4